# How to regex match on number and NULL or substitute NULL with zero

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have the following text in a file and looking to match on the number and NULL (string).

```
Seconds_Past_Audit: 2

Seconds_Past_Audit: NULL
```

I am expecting the end result to be:

```
2
NULL
```

If the NULL can be substituted with a zero, even better,

I've started with the following regex and it matches on the number only.

```
\s*Seconds_Past_Audit:(?P<milliTime>\s*\d*\.?\d*)
```

Comment: What are valid number formats? Looks like `.` would be valid as would `1.`, `.1`, and `1.1`, are these all correct?

Comment: Maybe `\s*Seconds_Past_Audit:(?P<milliTime>\s+(\d+(\.\d+)?|NULL))` would work for you? Might also want to use `\h` instead of `\s` if only horizontal spaces are expected and this is being used with PCRE

Comment: The sample above is saved in a text file with no data type defined. Essentially, all values are strings.

Comment: You cannot substitute while matching at the same time. Right now, even `:\s*\K.+` [will work](https://regex101.com/r/aCF1Vg/1). Where are you doing this?

Comment: The regex is for use in a [New Relic (NRQL)](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/query-your-data/nrql-new-relic-query-language/get-started/introduction-nrql-new-relics-query-language/) query using their [capture function](https://newrelic.com/blog/how-to-relic/using-regex-capture). Query with regex is: `SELECT count(*) FROM Log WHERE ''environment'' = ''LIVE'' AND numeric(capture(message, r'\s*Seconds_Past_Audit:(?P<milliTime>\s*\d*\.?\d*)')) > 1 since 1 day ago`